# Add style to specific element angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following block of code in the front-end:

```
<li *ngFor = "let cat of this.dataCategory.iconTitleSet" (click)="getTypeFromCategory(cat.title)" class="list-group-item puntero">
    <img [src]="cat.icon"  alt="icon" title="icon" />{{cat.title}}
</li>
```

in the component:

```
getTypeFromCategory(tipo: string) {
    this.typeItem = tipo.toLowerCase();

    if (this.arrayTipo.includes(this.typeItem)) {
      const i = this.arrayTipo.indexOf( this.typeItem );
      this.arrayTipo.splice( i, 1 );
    } else {
      this.arrayTipo.push(this.typeItem);
    }
}
```

in synthesis what up to now does is add a value that I get from FRONTEND in an array in case it is not, and if it eliminates it from the array, but when I add it I also want to put a specific style, for example a yellow background, but this last I do not know how to do it, I do not know how to say to angular that I put a specific style in element "li" specific generated by an "ngfor" loop when I click on the element.

[this is the image in the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMTQx.png)

Comment: Use ngClass or ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

**HTML**

```
<li *ngFor = "let cat of this.dataCategory.iconTitleSet; let i = index" (click)="getTypeFromCategory(cat.title, index)" class="list-group-item puntero" [class.changeColor]="i == selectedValue">
<img [src]="cat.icon"  alt="icon" title="icon" />{{cat.title}}
```

**Component**

```
selectedValue: any;
getTypeFromCategory(tipo: string, index) {
     this.selectedValue = index;
    this.typeItem = tipo.toLowerCase();

    if (this.arrayTipo.includes(this.typeItem)) {
      const i = this.arrayTipo.indexOf( this.typeItem );
      this.arrayTipo.splice( i, 1 );
    } else {
      this.arrayTipo.push(this.typeItem);
    }
}
```

class `changeColor` will be applied to every list item selected.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it in some ways:**

**1.** to set a diffrennt `class` with [`[ngClass]=""`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to each `li` and style in css

for example:

```
<li *ngFor = "let cat of this.dataCategory.iconTitleSet;let i=index;" [ngClass]="'title_'+i" (click)="getTypeFromCategory(cat.title)" class="list-group-item puntero">
    <img [src]="cat.icon"  alt="icon" title="icon" />{{cat.title}}
</li>
```

**in css**:

```
.title_1{}
```

**2.** you can set it with [`[ngStyle]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) or `style.`

```
<li *ngFor = "let cat of this.dataCategory.iconTitleSet;let i=index;" [style.color]="cat.color" (click)="getTypeFromCategory(cat.title)" class="list-group-item puntero">
    <img [src]="cat.icon"  alt="icon" title="icon" />{{cat.title}}
</li>
```